# Zend Debugger includes wrong file (same filename, wrong path)

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-debugger

Zend Debbugger is including the wrong file.

It's including 

`/home/jlam/code/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos/includes/steps-ui.php`, rather than

`/home/jlam/code/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos-community-add-on/includes/steps-ui.php`

As you can see, the files have the same file name, but a different path.

**Here's what happens**:

I am using Zend Debugger v5.3 with Zend Engine v2.4.0, php 5.4 to debug Wordpress 4.2.1 with plugins BadgeOS 1.4.4 and BadgeOS Community Add-On v 1.2.0 (plus a few more non-pertinent plugins).

I get the following compile error in the Eclipse console:

`Compile Error: /tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos/includes/steps-ui.php line 23 - Cannot redeclare badgeos_steps_ui_admin_scripts() (previously declared in /home/jlam/code/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos-community-add-on/includes/steps-ui.php:18)`

`badgeos_steps_ui_admin_scripts` does not actually exist in `/home/jlam/code/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos-community-add-on/includes/steps-ui.php`

Zend Debugger is actually including `/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos/includes/steps-ui.php` twice when its not suppose to.

**Here's how I can tell**:

I have a breakpoint at `/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos-community-add-on/badgeos-community.php` at line 90.  where it is instructed to

`require_once( $this->directory_path . '/includes/steps-ui.php' );`

The value of `$this->directory_path` is  `/home/jlam/code/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos-community-add-on/`

However, if I do a step into at that point, the debugger ends up at line 18 of 

`/home/jlam/code/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos/includes/steps-ui.php`,

*not*

`/home/jlam/code/tenjin/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/badgeos-community-add-on/includes/steps-ui.php`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by http://www.kpsolution.com/php/zend-debugger-loading-wrong-file-while-debugging/115/, the path mappings were wrong.

There was an extra (and wrong) mapping in the custom web server for this project under `‘Windows’ -> ‘Preferences’ -> ‘PHP’ -> ‘PHP Servers’` .